# My subdirectories under $ORACLE_HOME are missing

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus, sysdba, environment-variables

Im using oracle 11g. I cannot access the software products since they are missing. When I cd to $ORACLE_HOME, there are no files under it. They are missing. I cannot access the sqlplus. What to do in this kind of case?

I have input the correct environment and path.

Comment: Restore the files from backup.

Comment: I dont have a backup.. Is there any other way for me to restore this?

Comment: was this a client-only install, or a full database server install (i.e. with instance configuration, datafiles, etc.)?

Comment: it is a full database server install. i am new to oracle and db. looking for some help

Comment: If you lost everything in the $ORACLE_HOME of a full database server install and you didn't have a backup, there most likely isn't anything you *can* do: that would have included instance-specific files (like your actual data) that you won't get back just from re-installing the software. Have you checked with the system administrator or DBA (assuming there is one) to see if they have any kind of backup?

Comment: `$ORACLE_HOME` is just an environment variable. Was it even set in your session? Where did you actually navigate in the filesystem?

Answer (score -1):

If you have created a database, you should have an entry in `/etc/oratab`. You can then use `oraenv` to set your environment variables. Run it as `. oraenv` (note the space after the dot), which will retain the setting in your shell, instead of running in a subshell.